# python Combining items in a list of lists based on contents

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists which will have a different amount of lists each time depending on other conditions. Each of the list contains 4 items. I want to say if elements 1,2,3 of two of the inner lists are the same, add element 0 and delete the duplicates. The list looks something like this:

```
 [
    [4, 'blue', 'round', None],
    [6, 'blue', 'round', None],
    [8, 'red', 'round', None],
    [10, 'red', 'round', None],
    [8, 'red', 'square', None],
]
```

I think making a new list might help but am not sure. I need the end product to be:

```
[
    [10, 'blue', 'round', None],
    [18, 'red', 'round', None],
    [8, 'red', 'square', None],
]
```

The amount of different lists inside the list will always be different. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add an example that compiles? Are those strings? Custom objects? I assume your "none" should be `None`?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and where you're roadblocked.  Then stackoverflow can help.   As a clue to get you started:  investigate `itertools.groupby` which is available after `import itertools`

Comment: Squinting at this to see what you're trying to do, nested lists seems like a really bad choice for a data structure. If you're trying to keep track of a number of "round red" things, then a dict like `objects['round']['red']` seems better overall.

Comment: Can you update the list to be either valid Python or clearly pseudocode?  For example, it's unclear if `none` is supposed to be `'none'` as a string or `None` as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, all you are doing is associating element 0 with a tuple defined as the last three elements of any given list.  Luckily, it's perfectly okay for a tuple to be a key of a dictionary!

```
from collections import OrderedDict
color_data = [[4,'blue','round','none'], [6,'blue','round','none'], [8,'red','round','none'], [10,'red','round','none'], [8,'red','square','none']]
data = OrderedDict()
for x in color_data:
    key = tuple(x[1:])
    value = data.setdefault(key, 0) + x[0]
    data[key] = value
color_data = [ [ value] + list(key) for key, value in data.items() ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the `groupby` from itertools with the original list sorted by the last three elements of the sublist:

```
lst=[[4,"blue","round","none"], [6,"blue","round","none"], [8,"red","round","none"], [10,"red","round","none"], [8,"red","square","none"]]

from itertools import groupby
[[sum(v[0] for v in g)] + k for k, g in groupby(sorted(lst, key = lambda x: x[1:4]), key = lambda x: x[1:4])]

# [[10, 'blue', 'round', 'none'],
#  [18, 'red', 'round', 'none'],
#  [8, 'red', 'square', 'none']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a counter to accumulate the results:

```
>>> in_data = [[4,'blue','round',None], [6,'blue','round',None], [8,'red','round',None], [10,'red','round',None], [8,'red','square',None]]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> for count, *keys in in_data:
...     counter[tuple(keys)] += count
...     
>>> counter
Counter({('blue', 'round', None): 10,
         ('red', 'round', None): 18,
         ('red', 'square', None): 8})
```

It's easy to transform back into the output format you asked for:

```
>>> [[count, *keys] for keys, count in counter.items()]
[[8, 'red', 'square', None],
 [18, 'red', 'round', None],
 [10, 'blue', 'round', None]]
```

I agree with the commentators that you could use a better data structure than a list here.

My example uses some python3.5 specific syntax, if you're on an older version you should prefer the answer from [2ps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110438/674039) which implements the same idea.

Comment: Small note for the curious: using `defaultdict(int)` instead of `Counter` here would probably result in performance gains since `Counter` has a Python implementation backing whereas `defaultdict` has `C` code behind it. (I believe Python 3 made improvements to `Counter` performance though).

Comment: I can't find anything definite, like a PEP, but according to this [SO documentation entry](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/809/compatibility-between-python-3-and-python-2/4554/extended-list-set-and-dictionary-unpacking#t=201608232109186844294), `[count, *keys]` requires Python 3.5 or newer; not just any Python 3.

Comment: I guess `[count] + list(keys)` in <= 3.4

Answer (score 0):

if you feel like use pandas, you could do:

```
import pandas

data = [
    [4,"blue","round","none"],
    [6,"blue","round","none"],
    [8,"red","round","none"],
    [10,"red","round","none"],
    [8,"red","square","none"]
]

summary = (
    pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['q', 'color', 'shape', 'other'])
        .groupby(by=['color', 'shape'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'q': 'sum', 'other': 'first'})
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(summary)

  color   shape   q other
0  blue   round  10  none
1   red   round  18  none
2   red  square   8  none
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class that makes incrementing over a list of keys very convenient.

```
import collections

list_ = [
    [4, 'blue', 'round', None],
    [6, 'blue', 'round', None],
    [8, 'red', 'round', None],
    [10, 'red', 'round', None],
    [8, 'red', 'square', None],
]

counts = collections.Counter()

for i in list_:
    count = i[0]
    key = tuple(i[1:4])  # ex. ('blue', 'round', None) --> 6
    counts[key] += count

for i in counts.items():
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
(('blue', 'round', None), 10)
(('red', 'round', None), 18)
(('red', 'square', None), 8)
```

You can easily tweak this formatting to be exactly what you want.

Notes

- The use of `+=` without initializing the key first is not a typo.  Because a `Counter` instance returns a value of 0 for undefined keys automatically.
- I used `list_` over the variable name `list` in the original problem, because naming it that masks [the list(...) built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).
- The insertion uses a tuple because it's [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) to be a dictionary key, while a list is not since the list is mutable.
- Works in Python 2 / 3.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is your list of lists, then:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in a:
    key = tuple(row[1:])
    d[key] += row[0]

e = [list((val,) + key) for key, val in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
In [14]: e
Out[14]: 
[[18, 'red', 'round', None],
 [8, 'red', 'square', None],
 [10, 'blue', 'round', None]]
```

Comment: Another simpler option that's less flexible than `collections.defaultdict` but still worthy of consideration is `collections.Counter` for OP's use case of keeping sums.